# clang assembly output `BB#0` meaning

Tags: assembly, clang

```
int main(void)
{
    return 0;
}
```

Using `clang -S test.c` I could get the assembly file with the following content. What does `BB#0` mean, and where can I find more info on it?

```
...
main:                                   # @main
    .cfi_startproc
# BB#0:
    pushq   %rbp
...
```

Comment: It probably stands for "basic block number 0".

Answer (score 2):

Nothing. It's a comment.

It probably has some internal meaning, but can be ignored if you're not doing any development on LLVM / clang.

Comment: It's a comment, but it stands for "basic block number 0". See @Ross Ridge's comment.

Comment: @AlexDenisov Well, true. You would have to know how to related to that, though. I assume it's annotating the LLVM IR blocks, right?

Comment: I'd assume it is there for debugging purposes